# Extracting particular element in HTML file and inserting into CSV

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I have a HTML table stored in a file. I want to take each td value from the table which has the attribute like so  :

```
<td describedby="grid_1-1" ... >Value for CSV</td>
<td describedby="grid_1-1" ... >Value for CSV2</td>
<td describedby="grid_1-1" ... >Value for CSV3</td>
<td describedby="grid_1-2" ... >Value for CSV4</td>
```

and I want to put it into a CSV file, with each new value taking up a new line in the CSV.

So for the file above, the CSV produced would be :

```
Value for CSV
Value for CSV2
Value for CSV3
```

Value for CSV4 would be ignored as describedby="grid_1-2", not "grid_1-1".

So I have tried this, however no matter what I try there seems to be 
(a) a blank line in between each printed line
(b) a comma separating each char.

So the print is more like :

```
V,a,l,u,e,f,o,r,C,S,V,

V,a,l,u,e,f,o,r,C,S,V,2
```

What silly thing have I done now?

Thanks :)

```
import csv
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\test.html", 'r') as orig_f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f.read())
    results = soup.findAll("td", {"describedby":"grid_1-1"})
    with open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Deploy.csv', 'wb') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        for result in results :
            a.writerows(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If result is a string inside a list you need to wrap it in a list as writerows expects an iterable of iterables and iterates over the string:

```
a.writerows([result]) <- wrap in a list
```

In your case you should  use writerow and extract the text from each td tag in results:

```
  a.writerow([result.text]) # write the text from td element
```

You have all the td tags in your result list so you just need extract the text with .text.

Comment: If using `writerows`, I think it would have to be `a.writerows([[result]])` since the method expects an iterable of iterables.

Comment: Thanks very much all. This seems to print out the full <td>, all attributes and contents. Is there a way to print just the contents?

Comment: @SimonKiely, you need to extract what you want from the element, .text in this case I  imagine

Comment: @SimonKiely, `result.text` should extract the text

Comment: @rchang, yes but I think in this case writerow is the correct one to use.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Agreed.  Passing `[result]` looks considerably less ugly than `[[result]]`, at least to my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

use `lxml` and `csv` module.

1. Get all `td` text value which attribute `describedby` have value `grid_1-1` by `xpath()` method of lxml.
2. Open `csv` file in write mode.
3. writer row into csv file by `writerow()` method

code:

```
content = """
<body>
<td describedby="grid_1-1">Value for CSV</td>
<td describedby="grid_1-1">Value for CSV2</td>
<td describedby="grid_1-1">Value for CSV3</td>
<td describedby="grid_1-2">Value for CSV4</td>
</body>
"""
from lxml import etree
import csv
root = etree.fromstring(content)
l = root.xpath("//td[@describedby='grid_1-1']/text()")

with open('/home/vivek/Desktop/output.csv', 'wb') as fp:
     a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
     for i in l :
         a.writerow([i, ])
```

output:

```
Value for CSV
Value for CSV2
Value for CSV3
Value for CSV4
```

Comment: this will find all the td's not just the relevant, the OP already has the tags in the result list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes correct. OP has the tags. (corrected code to get `td`s with `describedby='grid_1-1'`)